# What is up-to-date way of grabbing frames from video file in c#?

Tags: c#, .net, video, media

As far as I know one way of grabbning frames from video files in C# is using MediaDet. However MSDN says that Media Detector(MediaDet) is deprecated: 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd390664(v=vs.85).aspx

What is the 'modern' way of getting frames from a video file using c#?

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for a thumbnail image from the video, take a look at FFMPEG.

there is a c# wrapper available . http://code.google.com/p/ffmpeg-sharp/

Checkout this link for a sample http://ramcrishna.blogspot.com/2008/09/playing-videos-like-youtube-and.html

Comment: I might be missing something but I couldn't find any downloads :-/

Comment: well i'm looking for it but the link uses ffmpeg as an external process which is not what I am looking for